# Changes in SAS functions made by proc fcmp does not get updated in Stored Process Server

Tags: sas, fcmp

In a few cases I´ve had trouble when trying to update functions in SAS made by in proc fcmp for all server types.

When running SAS-code(proc fcmp) in EG or in batchmode aiming to update functions in SAS for all server types. The changes is applied and works in EG() but in some cases it do not work in Stored Process Server or when running STP´s. It can lead to a forceable restart of SAS inorder to activate deployed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the CMPLIB catalog is cached in memory in other clients session.  What setting are you using for CMPLIB ?  Not sure what forceable restart you are doing, but consider:

- within session, clearing and resetting CMPLIB option
- within client, reconnect client for a new session, possibly logout login
- within server, restart the Object Spawner on the SAS Server